# Syntax Error in shell_exec but not in terminal

Tags: php, shell, syntax-error, shell-exec

I am trying to run a php script and do a loop. This is the code I use in terminal and it works:

`for i in {1..60}; do printf "file '%s'\n" video.mp4 >>list.txt; done`

However, if I try to call it in my php script as `shell_exec()`:

`shell_exec('for i in {1..60}; do printf "file '%s'\n" video.mp4 >>list.txt; done');`

I get error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''\n" video.mp4 >>list.txt; don' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/vagrant/Code/play/index.php on line 58
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''\n" video.mp4 >>list.txt; don' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/vagrant/Code/play/index.php on line 58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape single quotes.

```
shell_exec('for i in {1..60}; do printf "file \'%s\'\n" video.mp4 >>list.txt; done');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, the syntax error is gone now, however I run into another problem now. It is not looping 60 times now, instead it is looping 2 times. If I try putting 200 times, it loops 3 times. Do you have any clue? As I am in php, should i perform this task with php or is it slower?

Comment: It is better to use bash script for looping rather than PHP `shell_exec`. Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777992/loops-with-php-shell-exec-use-php-for-or-bash-for-do-done